# how to add class on body if owl first item active and remove class if last item is active?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried a lot to add a class on the body when owl first item is active and remove when the last child is active.

```
$('.slider2').owlCarousel({


    loop: false,
    items: 1,
    responsiveClass: true, autoplayHoverPause: true,
    autoplay: false,
    slideSpeed: 800,
    paginationSpeed: 900,
    autoplayTimeout: 3000,
    navText: ["<img src='images/left.png'>", "<img src='images/right.png'>"],
    onChanged: onChangedCallback
});
function onChangedCallback(event) {
    if ($(".slider2 .owl-item:first-child").hasClass("active")) {
        $("body").addClass("back");
    }

    else if ($(".slider2 .owl-item").last().hasClass("active")) {
        $("body").removeClass("next");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the part of the HTML code so that we understand the context better

Comment: plz check this one. https://codepen.io/w3codemasters/pen/eYOrNBJ

Comment: event.page.index should show you which slide is shown.

Comment: @RamSegev sorry I don't know much about jqyery.. can you plz tell where i have to change.. this is my demo url of codepen  https://codepen.io/w3codemasters/pen/eYOrNBJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the wrong callback function of Owl. If you use instead of onChange -> onDragged it works.

```js
$('.slider2').owlCarousel({
    loop: false,
    items: 1,
    responsiveClass: true, autoplayHoverPause: true,
    autoplay: false,
    slideSpeed: 800,
    paginationSpeed: 900,
    autoplayTimeout: 3000,
    navText: ["<img src='images/left.png'>", "<img src='images/right.png'>"],
    responsive: {
        0: {
            items: 1

        },
        360: {
            items: 1

        },
        768: {
            items: 2

        },
        1200: {
            items: 5

        }
    }, onDragged: onChangedCallback
});
function onChangedCallback(event) {
    if ($(".slider2 .owl-item").first().hasClass("active")) {
        $("body").removeClass("red");
        $("body").addClass("blue");
    }

    else if ($(".slider2 .owl-item").last().hasClass("active")) {
        $("body").addClass("red");
        $("body").removeClass("blue");
    }

}
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.carousel-wrap {
  margin: 90px auto;
  padding: 0 5%;
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
}

/* fix blank or flashing items on carousel */
.owl-carousel .item {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100; 
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
}

/* end fix */
.owl-nav > div {
  margin-top: -26px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  color: #cdcbcd;
}

.owl-nav i {
  font-size: 52px;
}

.owl-nav .owl-prev {
  left: -30px;
}

.owl-nav .owl-next {
  right: -30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.1.3/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">



<body class="blue">
  <div class="carousel-wrap">
  <div class="slider2 owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.1.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanx. but I want this on click of prev and next buttons.. plz check here. https://codepen.io/w3codemasters/pen/eYOrNBJ its not working correctly.    when last child ki active than red color not apply

Comment: Then it's the callback function onTranslated :)

Comment: onChanged is executed before the action is completed. onTranslated is executed after the action is completed

Comment: Nice if I could help. If I could give you the right answer, please mark as an answer :)